# Best practice for passing a type as a parameter in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection

I have a class that's supposed to recieve in the c'tor an implementation type (concrete class type) of some IStratagy interface, and create some objects of these recieved types.
Something like that:

```
Class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass(Class<IStrategy> strategyClass) {
        strategyClass.newInstance();
        // catch nasty reflection exceptions...
    }
}
```

I want to make sure that the parameter implements IStrategy.
I could recieve a parameter "IStrategy concreteStrategy" and then concreteStrategy.getClass().newInstance() but then it's still reflection which i'm trying to avoid..
What is the best practice for this problem in Java?

Comment: Uh, I cannot really see the problem. Doesn't `public SomeClass(Class<? extends IStrategy> strategyClass)` work for you at compile time?

Comment: What is doing strategyClass.newInstance();? why do you need another instance than the one passed, why don't you create cleanly a new Object

Comment: The truth is I need to recieve 3 parameters, each one is supposed to be a type that implements IStrategy. And then I need to create multiple instances of these types.

Comment: it's probably cleaner to pass your 3 parameters, or a list IStrategy[] strategies

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the following approach:

```
if( IStrategy.class.isAssignableFrom(strategyClass) ) {
          .....
}
```

Basically this is like instanceof, but without creating the actual instance of your concrete strategy implementation.

Hope this helps

Comment: But then I still have to use reflection to instantiate the dynamic type of IStrategy and catch exceptions.. Can't I escape the reflection somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Why not more simple like that:

```
Class SomeClass {
   public SomeClass( IStrategy strategyClass ) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Uh... this would require that the OP instantiates an object of the IStrategy class which seems to be the whole point of this constructor anyway...

Comment: This is what I suggested in the original question, but this solution involves reflection..